# How to retrieve TFS2010 projects from specific collection

Tags: tfs, project, tfs-sdk

I'm looking around for a good example to work with TFS 2010 collections,projects, and workitems to start with.

I am able to iterate through collections and Projects using the following code (thanks to original coder)

```
Dim tfsServer As String = "http://test.domain.com:8080/tfs"
    tfsServer = tfsServer.Trim()
    Dim tfsUri As Uri
    tfsUri = New Uri(tfsServer)
    Dim configurationServer As New TfsConfigurationServer(tfsUri)
    configurationServer = TfsConfigurationServerFactory.GetConfigurationServer(tfsUri)

    ' Get the catalog of team project collections
    Dim collectionNodes As ReadOnlyCollection(Of CatalogNode)
    Dim gVar As Guid() = New Guid() {CatalogResourceTypes.ProjectCollection}
    collectionNodes = configurationServer.CatalogNode.QueryChildren(gVar, False, CatalogQueryOptions.None)

    Dim strName As New StringBuilder
    Dim strCollection As New StringBuilder

    For Each collectionNode In collectionNodes
        Dim collectionId As Guid = New Guid(collectionNode.Resource.Properties("InstanceID"))
        strName.Length = 0
        Dim teamProjectCollection As New TfsTeamProjectCollection(tfsUri)
        teamProjectCollection = configurationServer.GetTeamProjectCollection(collectionId)
        Response.Write("Collection:" & teamProjectCollection.Name & "<br/>")

        ' Get a catalog of team projects for the collection
        Dim hVar As Guid() = New Guid() {CatalogResourceTypes.TeamProject}

        Dim projectNodes As ReadOnlyCollection(Of CatalogNode)
        projectNodes = collectionNode.QueryChildren(hVar, False, CatalogQueryOptions.None)

        ' List the team projects in the collection
        For Each projectNode In projectNodes
            strName.AppendLine(projectNode.Resource.DisplayName & "<br>")
            'System.Console.WriteLine(" Team Project: " + projectNode.Resource.DisplayName)
        Next

        Response.Write(strName.ToString())

    Next
```

I want to read specific project from a collection and iterate through workitems (tasks,bugs,issues,etc). Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can run any query you like in the `teamProjectCollection` - level with:

```
        WorkItemStore workItemStore = (WorkItemStore)teamProjectCollection.GetService(typeof(WorkItemStore));
        WorkItemCollection queryResults = workItemStore.Query(query);

        foreach (WorkItem workitem in queryResults)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(workitem.Title);             
        }
```

Now you only have to formulate the `query` - string in something that provides you with what you need.

Queries are [WIQL](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/tfsworkitemtracking/thread/f7087804-fd47-470d-8776-fc16b0b60ac7/) - like. This very basic can give you all work items within a TeamProject:

```
SELECT [System.Id], [System.WorkItemType], [System.Title], [System.AssignedTo], [System.State] FROM WorkItems WHERE [System.TeamProject] = @project
```

`@project` is in our case here the `projectNode.Resource.DisplayName`


(You can save any query you 've graphically set in TFS with 'Save as' as a *.wiq file & then use it's content programmatically)