# How to retrieve and save tasks(work items) from TFS2010 projects from specific collection

Tags: tfs, tfs-sdk

Thanks for the help about my earlier question answered few days back

[How to retrieve TFS2010 projects from specific collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6840755/how-to-retrieve-tfs2010-projects-from-specific-collection)

Now, I thought that the above question will solve my problem of hitting a specific task and reading/saving the task. But I couldnt find a solution.

What I want is to have a function which take three parameters
SaveWorkItem(CollectionID, ProjectID, WorkItemID)

and then we can update the workitem within the project - collection.

Any help/pointers would be highy appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To retrieve tasks

```
public void RetrieveWorkItems()
    {
        var tfs = TfsTeamProjectCollectionFactory.GetTeamProjectCollection(new Uri("http://TFS:8080/TFS/DefaultCollection"));
        var workItemStore = tfs.GetService<WorkItemStore>();

        var wiqlQuery = String.Format( @"Select [State], [Title] From WorkItems Where [Work Item Type] = 'Task' Order By [State] Asc, [Changed Date] Desc"); ;


        WorkItemCollection witCollection = workItemStore.Query(wiqlQuery);
        foreach (WorkItem workItem in witCollection)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("ID: {0}", workItem.Id);
            Console.WriteLine("Title: {0}", workItem.Title);
        }
    }
```

To enter task

```
public void CrateTask()
    {
        var tfs = TfsTeamProjectCollectionFactory.GetTeamProjectCollection(new Uri("http://TFS:8080/TFS/DefaultCollection"));
        var workItemStore = tfs.GetService<WorkItemStore>();
        Project proj = workItemStore.Projects["ProjectName"];
        WorkItemType type = proj.WorkItemTypes["Task"];
        WorkItem workItem = new WorkItem(type);
        workItem.Title = "Task entered using API";
        workItem["Activity"] = "Configuration";
        workItem.Save();

    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, the above code is displaying all the tasks for ALL project. What I want is All tasks for a given Project.

Comment: Ok, got it. The secret is in the query

Dim wiqlQuery = [String].Format("Select [State], [Title] From WorkItems Where [Work Item Type] = 'Task' And [System.TeamProject] = '" & strProjectName & "' Order By [State] Asc, [Changed Date] Desc")

Thanks.